# How to change XML Node name in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I want to change XML Node name in C# ,
My code is,

```
string filepath = @"C:\JobDocuments\jobsxml.xml";
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
     doc.Nodes.Name = "jobs";
     doc.Save(filepath);
```

My XML file is,

```
<jobs>
-<Table>
  <title><![CDATA[ Country ]]></title> 
  <category><![CDATA[ Site Engineering / Project Management ]]></category> 
  <description><![CDATA[ sades ]]></description> 
  </Table>
</jobs>
```

I want output as follows,

```
 <jobs>
      <job>
      <title><![CDATA[ Country ]]></title> 
      <category><![CDATA[ Site Engineering / Project Management ]]></category> 
      <description><![CDATA[ sades ]]></description> 
      </job>
 </jobs>
```

Here i want to display `<job>` instead of `-<Table>`. I changed in Query but that is not giving proper order.

```
  SELECT '<![CDATA[ ' + JobTitle + ' ]]>' as title,
               '<![CDATA[ ' + JobCategory + ' ]]>' as category,
               '<![CDATA[ ' + JobDescription + ' ]]>' as [description]
        from Jobs FOR XML PATH('job')
```

Please Help me out.
Thank you

Comment: Basically you want to change Table for job? where is the problem changing jobsxml.xml? it's because is created from another source?

Comment: I write you how to do it in your last question, looks like you don't do it ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
String sampleXml = "<jobs><Table><title><![CDATA[ Country ]]></title> <category><![CDATA[ Site Engineering / Project Management ]]></category> <description><![CDATA[ sades ]]></description> </Table></jobs>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(sampleXml);

            XmlNode rootE = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("jobs")[0];
            XmlNode oldE = rootE.SelectSingleNode("Table");
            XmlNode newE = xmlDoc.CreateElement("job");
            rootE.ReplaceChild(newE, oldE);
            while (oldE.ChildNodes.Count != 0)
            {
                newE.AppendChild(oldE.ChildNodes[0]);
            }
            while (oldE.Attributes.Count != 0)
            {
                newE.Attributes.Append(oldE.Attributes[0]);
            }
```

Comment: Note on this: The good solution would be change the xml itself instead to use logic to do it...

Comment: Thank you @mpacheco, I am getting error 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

Comment: I see a hyphen near to <Table>, is in your file?

Comment: Can you not just change the XML?